# Starting Apollo Server

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

Hey I'm startin to learn graphQL by doing the [Frontend Masters' course Introduction to GraphQL](https://frontendmasters.com/courses/graphql/graphql-exploration-exercise/) ([repo](https://github.com/FrontendMasters/intro-to-graphql)).
I would start by the context, but I look everywhere and nothing, also I tried to change it but it´s always the SAME output. If someone could help I'll be very, very grateful.

I'm trying to start the server with the next code:

```
    import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server'
    import { loadTypeSchema } from './utils/schema'
    import { authenticate } from './utils/auth'
    import { merge } from 'lodash'
    import config from './config'
    import { connect } from './db'
    import product from './types/product/product.resolvers'
    import coupon from './types/coupon/coupon.resolvers'
    import user from './types/user/user.resolvers'
    
    const types = ['product', 'coupon', 'user']
    
    export const start = async () => {
      const rootSchema = `
        type Cat {
          name: String
        }
        
        type _Query {
          myCat: Cat
        }
        
        schema {
          query: _Query
          mutation: Mutation
    }
      `
      const schemaTypes = await Promise.all(types.map(loadTypeSchema))
    
      const server = new ApolloServer({
        typeDefs: [rootSchema, ...schemaTypes],
        resolvers: {
          _Query: {
            myCat(){
              console.log('Hello there')
              return {name:'Ivar'}
            }
          },
          async context({ req }) {
            const user = await authenticate(req)
            return { user }
          }
        }
      }
      )
    
      await connect(config.dbUrl)
      const {url} = await server.listen({port: config.port})
      console.log(`GQL server ready at ${url}`)
    }
```

db file:

```
    import mongoose from 'mongoose'
    import options from './config'
    
    export const connect = (url = options.dbUrl, opts = {}) =>
    { return mongoose .connect(url, {
      useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
        .then(() => console.log('Database Connected'))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))

}
```

The curious thing is that in some moment it worked well, I've made changes, but not important ones.

The console output is this:

```
    ...
    $ node dist/index.js
    (node:17124) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: "context" defined in resolvers, but not in schema (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
    (node:17124) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
    (node:17124) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
    [nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

I'm sure that is a silly bug but it's freaking me out.

Answer (score 1):

The [`context`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/apollo-server/#context) is part of the configuration object you pass to `ApolloServer`, not part of its `.resolvers` object.

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs: [rootSchema, ...schemaTypes],
  resolvers: {
    _Query: {
      myCat(){
        console.log('Hello there')
        return {name:'Ivar'}
      }
    },
  },
  async context({ req }) {
    const user = await authenticate(req)
    return { user }
  },
})
```

Comment: This is correct. To expand on this a bit, I would recommend that while you're learning, use separate variables for the `typeDefs`, `resolvers`, etc. and pass them in as variables when you call new ApolloServer, rather than building your object all at once. It's easier to follow along with what is going where, and why. It's easy to accidentally move `context` up a line, but it's hard to accidentally nest it into a separate resolvers variable.